# State transition table for aho corasick algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, aho-corasick

Please help me to understand the construction of state transition table for more than one patterns in the Aho-Corasick algorithm.

Please give a simple and detailed explanation so that I could understand.

I am following [this](http://www.ijcsit.com/docs/Volume%204/vol4Issue3/ijcsit2013040318.pdf) paper and [here](http://blog.ivank.net/aho-corasick-algorithm-in-as3.html#comment-3953) is the animation for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, where is exactly your problem? What have you got so far from the algorithm?

Comment: Is your problem in Preprocessing Phase or FAILURE FUNCTION?

Comment: it's in preprocessing phase during construction of table.
how to fill the table with values and to associate the next state????

Comment: You'll find it *very* useful to download and study the original paper: [Efficient String Matching: An Aid to Bibliographic Search](http://www.win.tue.nl/~watson/2R080/opdracht/p333-aho-corasick.pdf). The paper is well written and quite approachable. You'll have to read it several times, though, and really think about it. But the construction of the state table is well explained.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Phase 1

**Creating the keyword tree** :

```
Starting at the root, follow the path labeled by chars of Pi
        If the path ends before Pi, continue it by adding new edges and ...
                            nodes for the remaining characters of P
        Store identifier i of Pi at the terminal node of the path
```

I demonstrate it by an example :

Suppose we have a finite set of patterns P = {he, she, his, hers}.

[image]

## Phase2

Next we extend the keyword tree into an automaton,to support linear-time matching as follows.

Obviously the automaton consists of two parts :

- states
- transitions

**States** : Exactly the nodes achieved by the keyword tree; and initial state = root of the tree.

[image]

**Transitions** : using ***goto(q,a)*** function as follows.

```
/*This function gives the state entered from current state q 
     by matching target char a*/
- If edge (q,v) in the tree is labeled by a, then g(q,a)=v; 
- g(0,a)=0 for each a that does not label an edge out of the root
//the automton stays at the initial state while scanning non-matching characters       
- O.W. g(q,a)={}
```

[image]

**Using the automaton** :

```
SearchofTarget T[1..m] //considering the target string T as an 
                     array of chars indexed from 1   to m
q:= 0; // initial state(root)
for i:= 1 to m do
    while g(q,T[i]) == {}  do 
        q:= fail(q); // follow a fail
    q:= goto(q,T[i]); // follow a goto
    if output(q) != {} then print i, out(q);
endfor;
```

As you see in the above pseudo-code it calls two functions : *fail(q)* and *output(q)*

***fail(q)*** : // for q !=0 gives the state entered at a mismatch

```
failure(q) is the node labeled by the longest proper suffix  w of L(q) ...
    s.t. w is a prefix of some pattern
//L(q) is the label of node q as the concatenation of edge labels ...
   on the path from the root to q
```

***output(q)*** :

```
gives the set of patterns recognized when entering state q
```

After computation of these two functions, the automaton looks like this :

[image]

Now you may wonder when to compute these methods, so please look at these for more official form :

[image]

Hope this help and if still something is ambiguous please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Can you please also elaborate: _Next wee extend the keyword tree into an automaton,to support linear-time matching._ I think it's key part.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: Yes, I'm working on it with MS Paint :)

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question it's useful.

But can you please explain how to fill the state transition table according to which we'll traverse in the trie while searching.

Comment: @Shail_42: Look, this algorithms can be split into two phases : 1-creating the keyword tree 2 - creating the automaton. So, indeed in the first phase there is no state transition but it's simply an edge between two nodes, nevertheless you can show this tree as a table. I edit the answer so please recheck it.